# How to find the coefficient of variation using the tapply function in R

Tags: r, tapply

I am trying to find the coefficient of variation in abundance using tapply in R and tried this code:

```
tapply(ReefFish$count, ReefFish$commonname, FUN = 100*sd(x)/mean(x))
```

However, I get the error:

```
Error in is.data.frame(x) : object 'x' not found
```

I am not sure what to put as 'x' since I am looking for the coefficient of variation in abundance (count) by their common name (commonname).

Does anyone know how I am supposed to define x in this code?

Comment: I used tapply to find the sd and mean, could I somehow use that here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking for an anonymous function with a variable `x`.

```
tapply(ReefFish$count, ReefFish$commonname, function(x) 100*sd(x)/mean(x))
```

Comment: Thank you. That worked! However, does it make sense to have values of, e.g. 1692.62851? Does that just mean there is a lot of variation?

Comment: Sorry, I not a stats expert so I can't comment on that. You may try posting the question here https://stats.stackexchange.com/